# Await operator works differenly in node app/openserver project

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I have `async` function like this.

```js
async function subscribeButtonHandler() {
    subscribeButton.disabled = true;
    const result = await Notification.requestPermission();
    if (result === 'denied') {
        console.error('The user explicitly denied the permission request.');
        return;
    }
    if (result === 'granted') {
        console.info('The user accepted the permission request.');
    }
    const registration = await navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistration();
    const subscribed = await registration.pushManager.getSubscription();
    if (subscribed) {
        console.info('User is already subscribed.');
        notifyMeButton.disabled = false;
        unsubscribeButton.disabled = false;
        return;
    }
}
```

It works as intended inside the node js application

But when I transfer this script to the Open Server project, link it in the same way, the browser gives me an error on the second await.

```js
const subscribed = await registration.pushManager.getSubscription();`
```

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pushManager')
> at HTMLButtonElement.subscribeButtonHandler (index.js:20:43)

For some reason, there is no such error inside the `nodejs` application and await are executed sequentially. I need awaits to work inside the OpenServer project.

Comment: The error means that the browser finds no registered service worker for the page context. Why do you think there should be one?

Comment: service worker registred succesfully, i have validation for this situation, i see this object in console. + when i check this variables with setinterval it works as i expected, but not with awaits

Comment: Well `await` definitely works in web browsers. It's possible that the code posted here is trying to get the registration object before the worker has loaded.

Comment: that function binded to button, even if i wait a bit after page loaded and click that button, same error happens

Comment: The point is that while I'm not sure exactly what's going on with your application, `await` definitely works, and your error is definitely that the `getRegistration()` call is returning `undefined`.

Comment: What is "*the Open Server project*"?

Comment: "*It works as intended inside the node js application*" - what is `navigator.serviceWorker` in node.js?